# Can I omit the username when using the FOS UserBundle with Symfony2?

Tags: authentication, symfony, fosuserbundle

I am using the [FOS UserBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle) for Symfony2. This UserBundle requires a username.

But for my application I would like the user to log in with the email address and a username shall be completey ommited in my app.

It was no bigger problem to manage, that the user can login with his email address (by following [this instruction](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/logging_by_username_or_email.md)).

So what steps do I have to go through to:

- Remove the username from the schema (if necessary, workarounds like username eq. email are also fine, please denote how this workaround would work)?
- Remove the username from all templates (register, login, forgot password etc.)?
- Make the whole UserBundle still work without the username?

Comment: The direct way would be to override the setter on the email address field. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10314932/fosuserbundle-login-with-email-symfony2

Comment: Yeah, question is a duplicate. Thanks for pointing to the original!