# FOSUserBundle login with email with service Provider, best practice

Tags: php, forms, symfony, authentication, fosuserbundle

I was looking to create a service provider in order to logIn with Email and not username with FOSUserBundle.

First I wrote this in my `security.yml` file according to the doc [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/logging_by_username_or_email.html):

```
security:
    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username_email
```

According to the **FOS** doc, I follow these [steps](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/1.2.0/Resources/doc/logging_by_username_or_email.md#logging-by-username-or-email) one by one.

Except in MyUserManager.php I wrote this (according to another question on stack [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10314932/fosuserbundle-login-with-email-symfony2)):

```
namespace Frontend\UserBundle\Model;

use FOS\UserBundle\Entity\UserManager;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UsernameNotFoundException;

class CustomUserManager extends UserManager
{
    public function loadUserByUsername($email)
    {
        /*$user = $this->findUserByUsernameOrEmail($username);

        if (!$user) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(sprintf('No user with name "%s" was found.', $username));
        }

        return $user;*/

        //Change it to only email (Default calls loadUserByUsername -> we send it to our own loadUserByEmail)
        return $this->loadUserByEmail($email);
    }

    public function loadUserByEmail($email)
    {
        $user = $this->findUserByEmail($email);

        if (!$user) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(sprintf('No user with email "%s" was found.', $email));
        }

        return $user;

    }
}
```

and of course I changed the User class in order to implement specific getter and setter like this:

```
namespace Acme\UserBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Acme\UserBundle\Entity\UserRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{

    // ...

    // override methods for username and tie them with email field

    /**
     * Sets the email.
     *
     * @param string $email
     * @return User
     */
    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->setUsername($email);

        return parent::setEmail($email);
    }

    /**
     * Set the canonical email.
     *
     * @param string $emailCanonical
     * @return User
     */
    public function setEmailCanonical($emailCanonical)
    {
        $this->setUsernameCanonical($emailCanonical);

        return parent::setEmailCanonical($emailCanonical);
    }

    // ...

}
```

But I owerride the FOSUser template form in `app\Resources\FOSUserBundle\views\Security\login.html.twig` like this:

```
{% block fos_user_content %}
  <form action="{{ path("fos_user_security_check") }}" method="post">

    <input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token }}"/>

    <label class="" for="username">E-mail</label>
    <input type="email" class="" id="username" name="_username" required="required"/>

    <label class="" for="password">{{ 'security.login.password'|trans }}</label>
    <input class="" type="password" id="password" name="_password" required="required"/>

    <label class="" for="remember_me">
      <input type="checkbox" id="remember_me" name="_remember_me" class="">
      <span class="">{{ 'security.login.remember_me'|trans }}</span>
    </label>

    <button class="" type="submit" id="_submit" name="_submit" value="{{ 'security.login.submit'|trans }}">
      LogIn
    </button>
  </form>
{% endblock fos_user_content %}
```

> It is the good way to only allow user Loged In with email field and
>   not the username?

Comment: Yes, you can use like this. I'am working like that and it is ok.

Comment: @MertÖKSÜZ thank you for reply, if It's good I hope that it could help other symfony lovers!

Comment: i hope too :) thank you.

Comment: This is also a related article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8832916/remove-replace-the-username-field-with-email-using-fosuserbundle-in-symfony2/21064627#21064627

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your approach resumes perfectly all mandatory changes for setup an email-password authentication on FOSUserBundle.

For now, I used only the same configuration in entity and security config (not need of the template because my login is done in AJAX).
The only doubt I have is the following :

As the `username` is always set using the `email` field value, is it useful to create your CustomUserManager ?
The loadByUsername will works if the username is always equal to the email, as done by your entity in `setEmail` and `setEmailCanonical`.

Is it just an additional security ?

**EDIT**

Change from username to email can involves to change some comportment in form building/validation.

Maybe you have to look at this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/21064627/4363634

Comment: as I could read on Symfony doc, the authentication process depends on `user providers`. When a user submits an email and password, the authentication layer asks the configured user provider to return a user object for a given argument (here email). So I owerride the UserManger to stay fit with the doc. I just following the doc in order to be sure it is the best practice. I hope you understand what I would like to do and it could help you if you need it.

Comment: Ok it's clear for me now, I have much to learn and to read documentation about how security is handled in Symfony. 
I will search about that and surely apply your logic for next to ensure a maximum of use cases. Thank's for your reply.

Comment: you're welcome. I post this question here in order to be sure I have created the right practice/method and to have some other developpers suggestions if it's not. I am happy if this could help you.

Comment: See edit in my answer, I've added a link about form building/validation that can be helpful for you (For your register/login forms)

Comment: thank you, I 'm just trying to follow this step right now.